# Using a custom Journey Builder platform activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, platform-activity

I'm working through the steps in [Creating V1 Platform Activities](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/platform/creating-platform-activities.html).

**When or how does a platform activity appear in Journey Builder?**

Does it need to satisfy all the requirements listed in the [Common Issue Checklist](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/platform/creating-platform-activities.html#common-issue-checklist) before it will appear? If it doesn't meet one of the requirements, is there a way to figure out what it is failing on?

In the App Center my platform activity appears as:

[image]

It has the category of Messaging. I was expecting it to appear under Messages in the Journey Builder Activities.

[image]

I'm using Journey Builder in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud account that I linked to in the [Connect Your app to an account](https://code.exacttarget.com/getting-started/setting-up-your-development-environment.html#connect-your-app-to-an-account) step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more [detail here](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node) regarding how to get your custom activity going.  For your first activity I'd follow that example to get one under your belt.  The activity should show up after the App Center entry is created and your app has been deployed. JB reads the config.json file when entering the dashboard for an interaction.  If there's an error in the config.json file, or JB can't find that file, it won't load.  Also, try changing the type to REST.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working through that example now. I'm finding some of the documentation required for the Pre-Requisites confusing. For instance, in [Setting up Your Development Environment - App Center](https://code.exacttarget.com/getting-started/setting-up-your-development-environment.html#app-center) it refers to creating a "Server-to-Server" app. As best I can tell this is now called an "API Integration". There are so many of these small differences in setting up the requirements to getting the basic demo I'm concerned I'll get something wrong.

Comment: If you are only creating a custom activity, you'll want to choose Application Extension in App Center.  You'll see this discussed in the Readme, section "Creating our base app in App Center."

Comment: I've got enough of the Desk.com API example working that the custom activities are appearing in Journey Builder and can be configured. I think that gives me a good starting point to start making my own version.