# Journey builder custom activity - custom activity doesn't show in journey builder, why?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

My question is the same as [this question here on stack exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70205/using-a-custom-journey-builder-platform-activity) but the answer did not help. I also followed the github guide in the answer but still no luck.

I want to create a custom activity in journey builder and i have followed [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm) step-by-step guide on salesforce as well as [this][3] guide to create the app extension in app center.

My custom activity still doesnt show in journey builder after i launch the app. I have the project structure exactly the same as the guide but there are still some kind of connection issue. Can someone get me in the right direction on where to search for errors? I host the UI application on Heroku as in the guide.

UPDATE: I get no logs in my heroku web application when I try to launch the customActivity application from app center which probably means that marketing cloud isnt communicating with my heroku web application.

I have specified the application keys in the config.json file which is reachable. The endpoint URL is set to https://appname.herokuapp.com.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are getting in console or on UI ?

Comment: Im not getting any error message - thats why i need guidance of what i've possibly missed.

When i launch the app from app center, no icon of my custom activity is shown in the builder (where icons such as "Send Email" and "Update Contact" is located).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question - in app center, the public extension in the activity settings weren't set to "This application and other installed applications". After changing this setting the custom activity appeared in JB.